# How to make benas/jPopulator work with lombok

Tags: java, testing, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

In my project I am using lombok library to hide boilerplate part of the code. Currently I am trying to auto-generate loads of data, so I'v selected benas/jPopulator library for this - it seems exactly what I need.

The problem is that I am getting following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property '***' has no setter method in class ***
```

While there are no other setters and getters, but Lombok's one it seems that jPopulator doesn't see them. While code is compiled well and application is running completely fine.

Are there ways to make these 2 libs work together?

**UPDATE**
It seems that the issue is not with jPopulator itself but with underlying library `org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean`, which can't find accessor method and fails. On another side in master version of jPopulator guys started to set properties on their own:

https://github.com/benas/jPopulator/blob/jpopulator-1.2.0/src/main/java/io/github/benas/jpopulator/impl/PopulatorImpl.java#L185
vs

https://github.com/benas/jPopulator/blob/master/jpopulator-core/src/main/java/io/github/benas/jpopulator/impl/PopulatorImpl.java#L260

The only question is there a way to use master version via maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [issue 42](https://github.com/benas/jPopulator/issues/42), the problem is with lombok's `@Accessors(chain = true)` which generates fluent getters and setters that are not compliant with Java Bean standard definition. That's why apache common's `PropertyUtils.setProperty` does not find the standard setter.

jPopulator is intended to populate **standard** Java Beans.

In regards to how to use the current snapshot version via maven central, it is documented [here](https://github.com/benas/jPopulator/wiki/Getting-Started#maven-usage).

Hope this helps.
Kind regards.
Mahmoud